# How do I convert a batch extension files from .csv file to a .txt

Tags: python, regex, windows

How do I convert a batch extension files from .csv file to a .txt
I have much files with .csv and i need change all them to .txt.

Comment: You just want to rename the files right?

Comment: At the moment what you're asking is ambigious.. Could you elaborate and try to explain in further detail what you have, and what you want to achieve... ?

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a [`rename()`](http://php.net/rename) function that you can use in a loop. E.g. to rename all the .csv files in the current directory to .txt:

```
foreach (glob('*.csv') as $filename) {
    rename($filename, rtrim($filename, '.csv') . '.txt');
}
```

Comment: LOL. Okay, indeed, that's one valid interpretation of this question.. I was going to ask for clarification on how the *contents* of the CSVs would be represented in a text file, but perhaps only renaming the extension is enough.

Comment: i need a software or a way for converting the extension , i'm not using php

Comment: Then why did you tag the question with php?

Comment: If you need "software" to do this, then why did you tag it as `php`? @user2658187

Comment: So why is this question tagged with `PHP`?

Comment: Lordy, everyone had the same question (for the OP) at the same time LOL!

Comment: Sidenote: This `foreach (glob('*.txt')` should probably be `foreach (glob('*.csv')`

Comment: @Fred-ii- gah. fixed.

Comment: I will +1 this, because it makes sense.

Comment: i want just change extension of file from csv to txt , sorry for begin unclear , and sorry for those who asking why i select php , its mistake

Comment: Then what George posted will work. Put it on your server and run it, making sure all `.csv` files are together and make a copy of them first. @user2658187

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to change any of the contents of the files? Or just change the extensions?

Changing the extension is easy. Just loop through the files, and use

```
shutil.copyfile(src, dst)
```

to copy the file to the new location with the new name.

Alternatively, if you just need to rename, try

```
os.rename(src, dst)
```

http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.rename

You'll need to use `str.split(".")` to cut off the old extension, and manipulate to add the new extension.

hope this helps.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html
http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Comment: Why copy when you can rename?

Comment: Is the “why copy when you can rename” really the reason for the downvote? You can’t be serious with an unclear question like this…

Comment: Fair point. Thought that was what he was asking. Edited :)

Answer (score 0):

Two items to consider - the file extension - rename the file - and then the delimiters to separate data and signal end of lines.   Also consider Unix vs windows machines have different end of line characters too.